# if the user chooses not to input double, how do I call a default value that is in another class separate from main?

Tags: c#, class, methods, null, double

the output prints "enter salary:"
how do I allow it to be null and if null it calls a default salary type double.
if user chooses to input salary, use this salary type double.??

Comment: please show the code that gets input from the user that you're referring to so we can see what needs to be done. Also, what type of project is this?

Comment: `double value = userInput ?? someOtherClass.DefaultValue;`